# Iphone app does not update automatically when you rename it in the iTunes

Tags: iphone, itunes, rename, app-store-connect

When I **rename** an **already** uploaded app in iTunes Connect, the update is ok, but people who have already downloaded this app before don´t receive any update. Can I make any change in my second upload to avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

However, there are two names you need to consider. The (usually longer) store name that is set in iTunesConnect, and the (usually shorter) "Bundle Display Name" this is set in Xcode and goes into your app's plist file.

Comment: But what could be the reason of the lack of automatic update of my app?

Comment: To clarify something else, I had modified the bundle version to a bigger one, before uploading it.

Comment: Just changing data in iTunesConnect is different than submitting an update and will not notify users. Only uploading a new binary will do that.